# Amazon SP-API can't assume role of myself?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to connect to the Amazon Selling Partners API (SP-API) using the node.js library and am coming across an extremely odd error which seems to be telling me I can't assume my own role?

```
CustomError: User: arn:aws:iam::11111:user/bob is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::11111:user/bob
```

I'm fairly new to AWS but I'm pretty sure that this inline policy for the user should be sufficient for what I'm trying to do, I've even made it work for all resources rather than just the SellingPartners role I'd previously created:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my full code in case it helps:

```
const SellingPartnerAPI = require('amazon-sp-api');
    
    (async() => {
    try {
        let sellingPartner = new SellingPartnerAPI({
            region:'na', // The region to use for the SP-API endpoints ("eu", "na" or "fe")
            refresh_token:'xxxxxx', // The refresh token of your app user
            credentials:{
                SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_ID:'xxxxx',
                SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_SECRET:'xxxxx',
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:'xxxx',
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:'xxxxx',
                AWS_SELLING_PARTNER_ROLE:'arn:aws:iam::11111:user/bob'
            }
        });
        let res = await sellingPartner.callAPI({
            operation:'getOrders',
            endpoint:'orders'
        });
        console.log(res);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: The ARN `arn:aws:iam::11111:user/bob` describes a **User** not a role. It should probably be something like `arn:aws:iam::11111:role/your-role-name`

Comment: @Maurice thanks, pretty sure that was it as I'm now getting a different error message (CustomError: Access to requested resource is denied). Happy to mark it as correct if you write it as an answer! Any chance you have an idea where to start looking with the new error? I've been following exactly these instructions https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#creating-and-configuring-iam-policies-and-entities

Comment: I've added the answer. The new error message is very vague, I haven't worked with the Selling Partner API, so unfortunately no clue. If you can get more details than that about the message you could ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARN `arn:aws:iam::11111:user/bob` describes a **User** not a **role**.

It should probably be something like `arn:aws:iam::11111:role/your-role-name` if the client expects a Role ARN.